# Why does setting element.className = null result in class="null"?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Apparently, attempting to set the `className` property to null doesn't erase the `class` attribute — instead, it replaces it with a class name that's literally called "null":

```js
document.querySelector('p:nth-of-type(2)').className = null;
```

```css
p[class]::before {
  content: '<p class="' attr(class) '">';
}

p:not([class])::before, p[class=""]::before {
  content: '<p>';
}

p.null {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="a b c">
<p class="x y z">
```

On top of that, there is full interop.

I would have expected `className = null` to erase the `class` attribute, or that `null` would convert to an empty string for the purposes of `className`, or at the very least that it would produce a TypeError.

What gives?

Comment: The HTML (`<p>...`) in your `content` property is not going to work as you expect.

Comment: @torazaburo: It does work as I expect - outputs "<p>..." literally. My intended use of the `content` property was to reflect the markup in the output. It does not work as some readers might expect, though. Perhaps I should amend it to prevent confusion.

Comment: *n.b.:* HTML does not understand the concept of `null`, it's a **Markup language** and works on *text* (`String`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript, `null` does not convert to an empty string. It converts to the string `"null"`. You can see this if you convert it manually:

```
var x = String(null);
console.log(x);
```

This is also mentioned in MDN's documentation of [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMString):

> Passing `null` to a method or parameter accepting a `DOMString` typically stringifies to `"null"`.

The `className` property (and related properties like `id`) are of type `DOMString`, which maps directly to `String` in JS. It's this conversion that results in a class name literally called "null", which is then reflected in the `class` attribute and matched by such selectors as `.null` and `[class~=null]`.

If you were expecting `null` to convert to an empty string because both are falsy values, it doesn't work that way. Just because two values are falsy, i.e. both values result in `false` when converted to Boolean, does not make those two values equal to *one another*, not even loosely. In particular, most objects, including strings, are never loosely equal to `null`, since something cannot be equal to nothing (with a few exceptions for legacy reasons). There is a handy comparison table [here in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using_.3D.3D) that you can refer to.

To erase the `class` attribute and remove all class names from an element, set `className` to the empty string instead of null:

```js
document.querySelector('p:nth-of-type(2)').className = '';
```

```css
p[class]::before {
  content: '<p class="' attr(class) '">';
}

p:not([class])::before, p[class=""]::before {
  content: '<p>';
}

p.null {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="a b c">
<p class="x y z">
```

(You can also iterate `classList` and remove each class individually, if [browser compatibility is not a concern for you](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist). Interestingly, for the performance junkies, modifying `classList` is actually faster than setting `className` — see the comment below. Presumably, setting `className` has the side effect of also updating `classList`, which could be the reason why it's slower.)

Comment: quite counter-intuitive, iterating over `classList` would be [faster](http://jsperf.com/empty-classname-vs-classlist/2) when targeting *[newer  browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList)*